# Least Squares Approximation of a Function on a Interval Different of the Limits of Integration of the Scalar Product of the Space

Tags: numerical-methods, least-squares, approximation-theory

Suppose we want to approximate a function $f(x)$ on a interval $[c,d]$ by, say, a linear polynomial $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x$ using the scalar product $$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_a^bw(x)f(x)g(x)\,dx,$$ where $w(x)$ is some weight function.

My question is: If the interval $[c,d]$, on which I want to approximate $f$ by $p$, is different than the limits of the integration of $\langle f,g\rangle$, I must change those limits to the same of the interval or do some different change (or no change at all), in order to have the proper approximation in that interval?

Comment: if you are free to choose $w(x)$, simply choose it to be zero outside $[c,d]$.

Comment: Ok, so if my scalar product is just $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx$, then I must set $a = c$ and $b = d$?

Comment: It depends on what $a$ and $b$ indicate. If you are treating the functions as members of $L^2(\mathbb{R},[a,b])$ for arbitrary $[a,b]$, then the optimal approximation on $[c,d]$ is produced by regarding the functions as members of $L^2(\mathbb{R},[c,d])$. If $a$ and $b$ are fixed however, this isn't necessarily the case because the two inner products aren't the same.

Comment: This question came up to me because I got an exercise where $a=0$ and $b=1$ but $c=-1, d=1$ so I don't know if I must calculate the inner products from $0$ to $1$ or $-1$ to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may seem unusual but $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ can indeed be different within the domain.

You are to find the best approximation with respect to a given norm (inner-product induced) from a given subspace ($span\{x^0,x^1\}$); which is the same as to find the orthogonal projection using the inner product onto the subspace. The solution will be the best approximation in the whole domain. The norm provided a notion of "distance" between functions, and in principle it could be defined using an arbitrary interval within the domain.

Comment: I can't understand it. Changing the limits of integration would change the result, how could it be the best approximation for all the domain?

Comment: It may not look good outside the $[a,b]$, yet it'd be called the best approximation with respect to the given norm. If you're allowed to introduce your own inner product, it'd be more meaningful to align the two intervals.